# Tailwind weird behavior safari blur

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have such a strange problem with safari on mac when I want to put more than 110px through the blur. It works in Chrome. It's just a safari and I don't know what to do with it anymore. Could someone help? Thank you.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/daBCt9JMM2

I tried different values ​​and around 100px it stops working. It doesn't even work in a incognito mode

I thought it was some kind of bug, but it doesn't work even after the build.